# Where can we store a public/private keypair in Azure?

Tags: azure, certificate, key, private, public

Where can we store the pfx certificate in azure so that we can get the private and public key in secure mode using java application whenever we need it.

Comment: Did you try to use Azure Key Vault?

Comment: Simplify title.

Comment: I want to use java api to get private and public key

Answer (score 0):

Use Azure Key Vault to store the certifice

> Azure Key Vault enables Microsoft Azure applications and users to store and use several types of secret/key data:
>
> - Cryptographic keys: Supports multiple key types and algorithms, and enables the use of Hardware Security Modules (HSM) for high value keys.>
> - **Certificates: Supports certificates, which are built on top of keys and secrets and add an automated renewal feature.**
> - Azure Storage: Can manage keys of an Azure Storage account for you. Internally, Key Vault can list (sync) keys with an Azure Storage Account, and regenerate (rotate) the keys periodically.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/about-keys-secrets-and-certificates

Access Key Vault with Java

http://www.stratogator.com/2017/10/20/how-to-access-secrets-in-azure-key-vault-using-java/

Comment: The following thing is pretty important in the docs: *When a Key Vault certificate is created, it can be retrieved from the addressable secret with the private key in either PFX or PEM format. The policy used to create the certificate must indicate that the key is exportable. If the policy indicates non-exportable, then the private key isn't a part of the value when retrieved as a secret.*

Comment: I think there is no way to get private key from the certificate of key vault using java application

Comment: I don't know java well enough to answer that but you can retrieve private keys from key vault. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/kv/2016/09/26/get-started-with-azure-key-vault-certificates/ ...", import a certificate and retrieve the certificate with or without private key to use it with an Azure application"